# VirtualBox doesn't see a raw disk by its DeviceID in Windows 7 (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)

Tags: virtualbox

Despite `\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE3` exists, seems like VirtualBox can't see it.

```
Pavel Serikov@PSerikovACELab /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox
$ wmic diskdrive list brief
Caption                                    DeviceID            Model                                      Partitions  Size
Hitachi HDS721050CLA362 SATA Disk Device   \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0  Hitachi HDS721050CLA362 SATA Disk Device   1           500105249280
PC-3000 ST500LT012-1DG14 SCSI Disk Device  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE3  PC-3000 ST500LT012-1DG14 SCSI Disk Device  1           500105249280
SAMSUNG HD103SJ SATA Disk Device           \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1  SAMSUNG HD103SJ SATA Disk Device           1           1000202273280
SSD Smar tbuy 120GB SATA Disk Device       \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2  SSD Smar tbuy 120GB SATA Disk Device       2           120031511040


Pavel Serikov@PSerikovACELab /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox
$ ./VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename D:\\usb.vmdk -rawdisk \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE3
VBoxManage.exe: error: Cannot open the raw disk '\.PHYSICALDRIVE3': VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
VBoxManage.exe: error: The raw disk vmdk file was not created

Pavel Serikov@PSerikovACELab /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox
$ ./VBoxManage internalcommands listpartitions -rawdisk \\.\PhysicalDrive3
VBoxManage.exe: error: Cannot open the raw disk: VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Pavel Serikov@PSerikovACELab /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox
$ ./VBoxManage internalcommands listpartitions -rawdisk \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE3
VBoxManage.exe: error: Cannot open the raw disk: VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Any idea how to fix ?

Comment: You appear to be using cygwin bash, which like all Unix shells uses backslash for its own purposes. Try single-quoting the argument that needs to contain backslashes i.e. `'\\.\PHYSICALDRIVEn'` or instead use CMD which doesn't treat backslash as special.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Cygwin, single-quoting fixed VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND problem :-) However when I mount resulted vmdk into existing virtual machine I got a wrong partition table: fidsk -l on a guest system showing 4 partitions with wrong start and end instead of one partition. Do you know what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by running cmd as administrator. Hope this helps.